# Can this mysql query(with union) be optimized?

Tags: mysql

i have this query configured by other guy that is taking a long time to execute and im wondering if there is any way to optimize it.

```
SELECT COUNT( t2.ticker ) /  '99' AS PctNewHigh_Yearlyarray 
FROM (
    SELECT t1.ticker, ROUND( SUM( t1.close ) , 2 ) as DailyChange
    FROM (
        SELECT b.ticker, b.close
        FROM broad b
        WHERE b.Date1 =  '2012-07-30 00:00:00'

        UNION

        SELECT b.ticker, MAX( b.close ) * -1 
        FROM broad b
        WHERE b.Date1 >  '2011-07-31 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY b.Ticker
        ORDER BY ticker
    ) t1 
    GROUP BY t1.ticker
) t2
WHERE DailyChange = 0
```

The database structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `broad` (
  `idbroad` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ticker` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Open` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `High` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Low` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Vol` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `TC2k_IG` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MS2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idbroad`),
  KEY `indx_Date1` (`Date1`),
  KEY `indx_Ticker` (`Ticker`),
  KEY `indx_High` (`High`),
  KEY `indx_Close` (`Close`),
  KEY `indx_TC2k_IG` (`TC2k_IG`),
  KEY `indx_Vol` (`Vol`),
  KEY `indx_Open` (`Open`),
  KEY `indx_Low` (`Low`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I hope you can help, let me know if more data is needed.
All the data are stock market data for example

```
INSERT INTO `broad` (`idbroad`, `Date1`, `Date2`, `Ticker`, `Open`, `High`, `Low`, `Close`, `Vol`, `TC2k_IG`, `MS2`) VALUES
(726, '2002-10-10 00:00:00', '20021010', 'A', 10.95, 11.13, 10.8, 10.85, 48534, 'EXAMPLE NAME', '');
```

Comment: Could you give us a brief description of what the query is supposed to return?

Comment: Does each ticker have only one 'close' per day?

Comment: Yes @jodaka ,i will update the question with one result.

Answer (score 0):

This should produce the same result, but be faster.

```
SELECT COUNT( t2.ticker ) /  '99' AS PctNewHigh_Yearlyarray 
FROM (
    SELECT t1.ticker, ROUND( SUM( t1.close ) , 2 ) as DailyChange
    FROM (
        SELECT b.ticker,
        MIN(CASE WHEN b.Date1 > '2011-07-31 00:00:00' THEN b.close * -1 ELSE b.close END) AS close
        FROM broad b
        WHERE b.Date1 >= '2011-07-31 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY b.Ticker
        ORDER BY NULL
    ) t1 
    GROUP BY t1.ticker
) t2
WHERE DailyChange = 0
```

You should post an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` from (maybe both, yours and mine) queries to know for sure if and which index is used. It might be better if you combined some indexes instead of having so many.